# Man who finds electricity in a dystopian society only to be driven into wilderness

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

I remember almost all of the story details except the name and author! Here are some bigger points:

- I believe it's an older story – between the 60s-70s.
- People in this future are encouraged to group-think. Doing something individually is considered dangerous and punished by death or exile.
- The hero works in the cleaning class of people and is in love with a woman who works in the agriculture class. They aren't allowed to speak so he loves her from afar.
- He presents his findings of electricity to his people's council expecting them to be as excited about it's potential as he is, but instead is pursued with the intent of a death sentence. He runs into the wilderness to escape them; this is huge because his society acts as though the world doesn't exist past the wilderness.
- The girl he is in love with follows him and they travel through the wilderness together.
- They find an old abandoned neighborhood and live in a large house together beginning their own paradise.
- Title might have something to do with the word “Paradise” or “Eden”.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an Ayn Rand story with that plot: ["Anthem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthem_%28novella%29). I haven't read it in rather a long time and can't recall a lot of detail.

---

Odd side note [Neil Peart credited the story with inspiring the story in the Rush album *2112*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2112_%28album%29#2112)

Comment: "Anthem" is it! Thank you so much!